# Using % as subscript in plotmath

Tags: r, plotmath

How can I use the percent symbol as subscript in a plotmath expression?

I am using the following script:

```
text(4.2,0.45, expression(paste(P[Con_30%Fat], "=0.611")), cex = 1.3)
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected input in "text(4.2,0.45, expression(paste(P[Con_30%Fat], "=0.611")), cex = 1.3)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, expression(paste(P[Con_30*"%"*Fat], "=0.611")), cex = 1.3)
```