# R plot title involving a subscript and value of a variable

Tags: r, plot, title, subscript

In R, the value of the variable MyVar should be evaluated and appear in the title of a simple R plot p.

```
MyVar<-0.23
```

The plot p is called using

```
plot(p, main = MyTitle)
```

My plot title needs a subscript and should look like this:
[image]

What is the correct statement for MyTitle= ?
I tried dozens of variations using paste, expression, substitute, and bquote. Nothing seems to work...

Any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks a bunch!
Mark

Comment: [answer to this question could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470026/using-as-subscript-in-plotmath) `plot(1, main = bquote(F[below]==.(MyVar)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can paste an expression to a variable (paste/print/cat/bquote/etc). As a workaround, you could use the "Fbelow=" expression as the title and use mtext to insert the value of MyVar, e.g.

```
MyVar<-0.23
plot(mtcars[2:3], main = expression('F'[below]*'='))
mtext(text = MyVar, side = 3, adj = 0.625, padj = -1.75, cex = 1.5)
```

[image: example.png]

Obviously this isn't ideal, but unless someone else has a clever way of solving your issue this will at least give you a potential option

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Solution highly appreciated! All best Mark